# how to access sensors and camera of android device from Shell

Tags: linux, android

I have logged in to my android phone through SSH [installed SSH client in android and through putty from windows]. Now I can access all the directories like root , dev , etc, of the phone.Can someone tell me what's the native method to access the devices and sensors of the phone ..I mean, how can I control say, the camera, just from this Linux shell terminal of the phone.

Regards, Kedar